# Why Flash call External interface not longer called in IE11?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer-11

I have this snippet:

```
<object id="myMovie" name="myMovie" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%" data="swf/myMovie.swf">
    <param name="movie" value="swf/myMovie.swf" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
</object>
```

and I use :

```
myMovie.doAction("hello world");
```

Which works great in FF, Chrome, IE9,IE10 but not in... IE11 !
Nothing happens !

What is wrong with that syntax on IE11 ?

Comment: i get the same issue . any updates on this thread ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue , upgrade flush plugin to recent version (13) . code work us it should be .